# tableView.tableHeaderView = UISearchDisplayController.searchBar; and call setContentInset: ; searchBar is not drawn when i scroll the table

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

tableView.tableHeaderView  = UISearchDisplayController.searchBar; 
and call setContentInset: ;

searchBar is not drawn when i scroll the table .
I want to know what's going on here.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UISearchBar * searchBar =[[UISearchBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView=searchBar;

    self.searchController =[[UISearchDisplayController alloc]initWithSearchBar:searchBar contentsController:self];

    //
    //(refreshing)
    //
    [self.tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(128, 0, 0, 0)];
}
```

[image: Picture]

please help me  ,thanks

Comment: You've set it as the header of the tableView so when you scroll so does the header. If you want it to be fixed or static don't put in your tableView header

Comment: Yes ageed to @soulshined, If you have **single section** in your table, then I would suggest you to add this in your section header view. Section header always persists, even you scroll till end.

Comment: @soulshined Thank you for your suggestions. My point is that there is something wrong with the search bar. When I scroll the tableView below, only part of the searchbar is shown on the screen instead of the whole bar is.

Comment: @finab : Have you tried with section header view?

Comment: @Mrunal Only happens in this case I describe ， T T

Answer (score 1):

```
- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        for (UIView * view in self.subviews) {
            view.clipsToBounds=NO;
        }
    }
    return self; 
}
```

Make a custom UISearchBar and overwrite init method

Comment: if you click searchBar , searchBar.subviews.clipsToBounds will change to YES. you can overwrite layoutSubviews method to keep it's value is NO;